# When installing firebase with swift in Xcode with cocoa pods, it gives me 27 errors

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

So, I've tried installing firebase into my application many times, each time it gives the same result, 27 errors. these are some of the errors...
[image: 27 errors]

I'm trying to install firebase though cocoa pods, this is my pod file...
[image: pod file]

And the terminal in which I install the pods...
[image: terminal]

So my real question is why I'm getting these errors. I've installed firebase in other apps and they are all working fine, please can someone help, I've uninstalled the pods and reinstalled them many times but nothing is changing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

wow, I just realised what was wrong after months of trying to figure it out. I still had the frameworks from when the application had parse databases, all's i did was delete the frameworks which were required for parse, and it built successfully. So happy!!!!!!!